# Dealing with <spans> in read_html output - edit to space or NL

Tags: python, pandas

My first post here :)

I am trying to pull a table from a website which I can do successfully using the following:

```
import pandas as pd
url = 'https://www.oddschecker.com/market-movers/horse-racing'
df_list = pd.read_html(url, header=None, skiprows=1)
df = df_list[0]
df_list
```

Nice and simple and works great to an extent.

The only issue I am having is with one column where the data is stored in  tags.

```
<a>
<span class="hide">1Newbury 13:15</span>
<span>Bravemansgame</span>
<span>Newbury 13:15</span>
</a>
```

What this means is when the data is output it looks like the following:

> 1Newbury 13:15BravemansgameNewbury 13:15

Ideally, I would like to replace the spans with either spaces or the intended new line so the text would look like this:

1Newbury 13:15 Bravemansgame Newbury 13:15

Is this possible with the current function?

Comment: do you really need the content in first span ? The second and third already represent name and event, with these two should be enough. I think it is not possible to do with pandas read_html as there is no parameter to do what you want, personally I would use bs4 to extract this column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use beautifulsoup for extracting information in span and later save the result in list. you need to do little bit  code manipulation  and finally you can replaced required dataframe column with list.This is one way to solve your issues .

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
ingo="""<a>
     <span class="hide">1Newbury 13:15</span>
     <span>Bravemansgame</span>
     <span>Newbury 13:15</span>
     </a>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(ingo, 'html.parser')
#print(soup)
spans = soup.findAll('span')
span_d=[]
#print(spans)
for span in spans:
    print(span.text)
    span_d.append(span.text)

print(span_d)
output=' '.join(span_d)
print(output)

1Newbury 13:15
Bravemansgame
Newbury 13:15
['1Newbury 13:15', 'Bravemansgame', 'Newbury 13:15']

'1Newbury 13:15 Bravemansgame Newbury 13:15'
```

Comment: Thanks - i think this will be the way I go